# Accessing JSON with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, get

I need to access some JSON with JQuery. For some reason, it's not working and since the getJSON method fails silently, I can't figure out what's wrong. I have checked that the JSON Url is correct. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('../src/json/baseball.json', function(data) {
            $("#add").html(data.baseball[0].levels[0].games[0].versus);
        });
        });
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <p id= "add"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON:

```
{"baseball":
[{
    "gender":"boys",
    "levels":[
    {
        "level": "varsity",
        "games":[
        {
            "versus":"Fullerton",
            "homeaway":"Home",
            "month":"February",
            "date":"27",
            "year":"2012",
            "troyscore":"32",
            "vsscore":"41",
        },
        {
            "versus":"Sunny Hills",
            "homeaway":"Away",
            "month":"March",
            "date":"28",
            "year":"2012",
            "troyscore":"20",
            "vsscore":"17",
        }]
    },
    {
        "level": "jv",
        "games":[
        {
            "versus":"Sonora",
            "homeaway":"Home",
            "month":"January",
            "date":"20",
            "year":"2012",
            "troyscore":"15",
            "vsscore":"21",
        },
        {
            "versus":"Valencia",
            "homeaway":"Away",
            "month":"April",
            "date":"30",
            "year":"2012",
            "troyscore":"40",
            "vsscore":"1",
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "gender":"girls",
    "levels":[
    {
        "level": "varsity",
        "games":[
        {
            "versus":"Acacia",
            "homeaway":"Home",
            "month":"February",
            "date":"27",
            "year":"2012",
            "troyscore":"32",
            "vsscore":"41",
        },
        {
            "versus":"LV",
            "homeaway":"Away",
            "month":"March",
            "date":"28",
            "year":"2012",
            "troyscore":"20",
            "vsscore":"17",
        }]
    },
    {
        "level": "jv",
        "games":[
        {
            "versus":"Commonwealth",
            "homeaway":"Home",
            "month":"January",
            "date":"20",
            "year":"2012",
            "troyscore":"15",
            "vsscore":"21",
        },
        {
            "versus":"Xishan",
            "homeaway":"Away",
            "month":"April",
            "date":"30",
            "year":"2012",
            "troyscore":"40",
            "vsscore":"1",
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

Comment: Although it's common for URLs to act kinda like filesystem paths, AFAIK it's not required -- and the server might not know (or, for security reasons, might actively forget) that `..` means "the parent directory".  Did you try an absolute URL?

Comment: What do you see in the console if you stick `console.log(data)` in front of `$("#add") ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the final properties of your inner objects have trailing commas, which makes your JSON badly formed. Just try pasting it into [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/). It will wine at every object's last property.

```
    {
        "versus":"Fullerton",
        "homeaway":"Home",
        "month":"February",
        "date":"27",
        "year":"2012",
        "troyscore":"32",
        "vsscore":"41", <-- borked JSON
    },
```

Complaint:

```
Parse error on line 67:
...                    },                 
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING'
```

`$.getJSON` will fail silently if the returned JSON is not strictly well-formed. I want to provide a reference from the docs, but it appears that the jQuery site is down....bleh.

Comment: That will still work in non IE browsers and it can't be the reason for not working.

Comment: It's not necessarily about browser, it's about jQuery only accepting well-formed JSON.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: This is JSON, not JavaScript. They are different specifications with different rules. http://jsfiddle.net/5n8Qz/

Comment: @amnotiam - JSON is JavaScript object nothing different. It is just a term used to represent it.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: That's just not correct. JSON is a text format whose structure is *modeled after* JavaScript, but it is not identical to JavaScript. See the example I added to my comment above. Parsing the JSON text that includes the trailing comma results in a SyntaxError in Chrome.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I just started using JSON, so I didn't realize extra commas could make such a big difference.  :D

Comment: @amnotiam - I meant to say the JSON object not JSON string. If you try to parse a json string which has trailing comma then parser will through error but if you have a trailing comma in the object browser still parses it without throwing error.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: But then it isn't JSON. Then it's JavaScript. That's why the browser doesn't care. They're different specifications with different rules.